# How to Record sound of Radio stream?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, audio-streaming

How to Record streaming-audio from radio stream link ? Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use VLC to record the stream. Just enter the address and Convert or Stream it to a file.

Comment: VideoLAN Homepage: `www.videolan.org/vlc`

Comment: no, I don't need a recorder, but I want to do a program which will do this.